# Post message from UI thread to worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to implement reading from a file, line by line. On each line, in case a certain condition is met, a Dialog window appears. The Dialog should have callbacks with returned result. Based on that result, the reading should continue with next line or break execution. I decided to achieve that with a separate worker thread for the reading, using the HandlerThread class, that communicates with the main thread, either with runOnUiThread() to open Dialog, or some Handler implementation. However, it is not very clear to me how to send the result back, from the UI to worker, and with blocking the worker until the result is received so it may continue with the next line. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using an event bus? (Pub / Sub  pattern in general)

Comment: I had a look at Otto, not aware of that pattern.

Comment: It is easy to use once you get the hang of it. I think it would fit perfectly for your scenario since Otto can post messages across multiple threads.

Comment: I'm not much into Android's multi-threading. All I've used so far is AsyncTask.

Comment: Otto is deprecated, in favor of RxJava and RxAndroid.

Comment: RxJava is a bit over kill for this particular task. Anything deprecated doesn't mean it is not usable. You can give both a try if you are willing to explore :)

Comment: RxAndroid seems like a simplified version, "minimum classes", of RxJava. In any event, I will use either RxA or Otto. Definitely suitable for the task, thanks, @Much Overflow!